# ASP.Net and x86 vs. x64

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cpu-architecture

Is there any guidance on choosing between x86 and x64 for ASP.Net MVC web apps?  I can find a few things for EXEs but nothing for web apps.

Yes I can just go with AnyCPU but if there is a reason to specifically target either I'd love to know.

Answer (score 0):

x64 makes sense only if your web app consumes large amount of memory, otherwise it's better to stick with x86. Only thing is specific to ASP.NET is production area - it's all about deployment and hosting/resources plans. There is a nice [blog post by Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/PennyPinchingInTheCloudYourWebAppDoesntNeed64bit.aspx) about it.